# При скроллинге пропадают отметки чекбоксов в айтемах ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

В `ListView` элементов больше чем влезает на экран. Каждый элемент `ListView` имеет `Checkbox`. При прокрутке со скрытых элементов снимается статус `checked`.
 Что сделать чтоб все сохранялось?

Comment: Вопросы про адаптеры в Android не перестанут существовать никогда

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для реализации чекбоксов в `ListView` есть три способа:

1. Использовать стандартные возможности API - установить списку режим `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` (альтернативный код `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`) и в качестве айтема использовать предоставленную API разметку - `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`.
   Данный вариант печалит аскетичностью оформления - строка текста и напротив чекбокс.
2. Действовать по примеру первого варианта, но создать собственную разметку. Данная разметка должна обязательно реализовывать интерфейс `Checkable`. [Пример](http://adanware.blogspot.ru/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html).
3. Создать кастомный адаптер, который будет хранить состояния (установлен или нет - например отдельный массив `boolean` или поле в модели для айтема) всех чекбоксов в списке. При изменении чекбокса записывать новое состояние в этот список, при создании айтемов в методе `getView()` принудительно устанавливать чекбоксам значения из данного списка.

Помимо различий в реализации, данные способы различаются и способами получения значений чекбоксов (а ведь именно для этого все и затевалось).

Первые два способа как бы "трувэй". Для получения чекнутых айтемов используется метод `ListView` - `getCheckedItemPositions()` (`getCheckedItemIds()` [как вариант](http://blog.clockworkbits.com/2014/05/26/list-with-checkable-items/)), который возвращает массив `SparseBooleanArray`, содержащий номера позиций, которые были **изменены**. Позиция находится в `key`, ее текущее состояние в `value`. [Пример1](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/listview.php#multichoice)

Способ хорош тем, что вы получаете такие плюшки, как методы: `isChecked()`,`setChecked()`, которые можете применять к отдельным айтемам "снаружи", например в активити . [Пример2](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-checkbox-example/) , а так же некоторые другие возможности, заложенные в стандартный API.

Третий способ - не "тру"-реализация, но гораздо проще и понятнее. Чтобы получить состояние чекнутости элементов просто добавляем в адаптер метод, который отдаст наше "хранилище" состояний чекбоксов, дальше вы уже можете использовать его по собственному усмотрению.
Способ хорош тем, что позволяет свободный вид айтема без заморочек с интерфейсом `Checkable` и свободный формат возвращаемых данных по чекнутым элементам. [Пример3](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter). Плата такова, что при этом любые дополнительные "возможности", которые в первом варианте реализует API, вам придется реализовать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 6):

Этот вопрос уже 1000 раз задавался. Нужно в `getView()` устанавливать состояние елемента. Это описано в любом мануале по `ListView`.

Comment: Скорее сохранять состояния чекбоксов при изменениях и востанавливать при отображении в `getView()`