# слушатель на checkbox из listview не работает

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

Создал listView с собственной разметкой, привязал к SimplApdapter
А в разметке есть checkbox,и мне нужно поставить на него слушатель.Я испробовал все, не получается.Как решить данную проблему?

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
smp = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.row,
                new String[]{"time", "label", "active"},
                new int[]{R.id.time_row, R.id.label_row, R.id.active_check_main});
listView.setAdapter(smp);
LayoutInflater factoryClient = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View view = factoryClient.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.active_check_main);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {}
});
```

Comment: Советую сразу переходить на RecyclerView. Ва будет проще потом, поверьте.

Comment: @andreich `RecyclerView` не универсальная замена `ListView` - у каждого виджета своя область применения и принимать решение нужно исходя из задачи. В частности `RecyclerView` не имеет режима `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` вообще - все придется реализовывать самостоятельно

Comment: @pavlofff В большинстве случаев listview придется кастомизировать. Реализовать множественный выбор - плевое дело, если уж на то пошло, решается буквально несколькими строчками. В общем я все равно настаиваю на RecyclerView. ListView остается нужен, но это уже скорей исключительные ситуации. И множественный выбор - не одна из них.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не можете просто так повешать слушатели на вложенные в айтемы списка виджеты из активити.

Для реализации слушателей такого рода, вам нужно либо создать кастомный адаптер на основе одного из стандартных и в нем при биндинге на айтем (метод `getView()` адаптера) прикреплять слушатель на вложенные `View`, либо использовать стандартные возможности системы - режим `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` для списка.

Кроме того, у вас появится проблема сохранения чекнутости элементов при прокрутке.

Подробности реализации вариантов списка с чекбоксами смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/177345)