# Как правильно заполнять ArrayList значениями типа boolean, взятыми из БД?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Есть локальная база данных с колонкой `"complete"` в которой хранятся данные типа `boolean` (отправляю `true | false` - записывается `1 | 0` соответственно). Также есть `ListView`, построенный на `SimpleAdapter`
 В каждом элементе списка присутствует `CheckBox`. Вот им то и надо программно присваивать значения `true | false`, взятые из БД. Но у меня никак не получается доделать задуманное, остановился на последней части. Вместо того, чтобы флажок при значениях `1` и `0` ставился / не ставился, справа от него просто показывается это значение (или `0`, или `1`). Так как, я делал по примеру отсюда http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/simpleadapter.php#customlayout2, я догадываюсь в чем проблема и понимаю, что она легкорешаемая)
В примере используется готовый массив `Boolean`- значений, я же заполняю `ArrayList`. А вот и мой код

```
final Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("products", new String[] {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_LIST, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE},  null, null,  null, null, null) ;  
final ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> arrTblCounts = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<Integer> arrTblComplete = new ArrayList<Integer>();

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("list"))==intValue) {
            arrTblNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            arrTblCounts.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("count")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")));
            arrTblComplete.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("complete")));
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    san = arrTblNames.toArray(new String[0]);
    myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map;
    for (int a = 0; a < san.length; a++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("MemberID", arrTblNames.get(a));
        map.put("Name", arrTblCounts.get(a));
        map.put("checked_product", arrTblComplete.get(a));
        myArrList.add(map);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, 
    myArrList, 
    R.layout.row, 
    new String[] { "MemberID", "Name", "checked_product" }, 
    new int[] { R.id.ColMemberID, R.id.ColName, R.id.chb_products});
    lv_products.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

При попытке поменять тип `ArrayList` на `Boolean` он ругается на код для взятия данных через курсор. Так как быть? В БД данные хранятся в виде чисел (`0` или `1`). Может их так и брать в `ArrayList` для типа `int`, а затем с помощью фильтра переделать его в `ArrayList` для типа `boolean`?

Comment: Не очень понятна проблема... Вам так, что ли, надо: `(arrTblComplete.get(a).equals("0"))?false:true)`? или `(arrTblComplete.get(a)==0)?false:true)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, проблема в том, что вместо того, чтобы чекбокс зависил от данных в ArrayList справа от него появляется это самое значение. Например в БД везде записаны единицы, а вместо активных чекбоксов справа от них однерки стоят

Comment: Ну... Сделать что-то более сложное чем отображание одной строчки в ListView с помощью встроенного адаптера вообще идея плохая. Вам бы лучше вообще не пытаться это сделать, а сразу на `RecyclerView` всё написать.

Comment: Попробуйте [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/177345) понять и применить. Для `RecyclerView` все то же самое, только всю эту функциональность вам нужно будет реализовать самостоятельно, так как для этого виджета ничего готового нет, но многие его зачем то любят :) .

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы бог кодинга! =) Спасибо, вообще забыл о тернарном операторе!

Comment: @pavlofff, неа) ListView я буду пилить до посинения, когда добьюсь максимума, пересяду на RecyclerView, хотя если честно мне этот виджет не по душе.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, ну я сам об этой штуке (как там вы его назвали?) не больше года знаю) Если предложенное решение помогло - то могу его в ответ написать.

Comment: Зря вы так с ListView. Я бы на вашем месте бежал от него подальше. Вот правда. `RecyclerView` - единственно нормальный способ отображать сложные списки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, давайте, поставлю галку

Comment: @pavlofff, хорошо, глянул в сторону этого RecyclerView. С ним сложнее просто.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, теперь чекбокс выполняет то что нужно, но видимо он заблокировал ListView. Не вызывается ни ItemClick, ни ItemLongClick.  Даже анимация выбор пропала. Только чекбокс менять можно и все

Comment: Я бы вам рекомендовал вообще отойти от чистой SQLLite в пользу какого-то ORM - со всеми этими курсорами, лоудерами, "сырыми запросами" и прочими "сопутствующими товарами" одни расстройства только. Для себя я выбрал ORM Realm, как чистый ORM, а не надстройку над SQLLite, но многие еще хвалят GreenDAO

Comment: @pavlofff, поддерживаю) Меня в своё время вообще SQL напугал и я использовал и использую `OrmLite` - там синтаксис очень понятен и никаких особых проблем с ним не имел.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, ну... Там, вроде, надо что-то типа `focusable` настраивать в разметке... Ну и вешать случатели нажатий на элементы снаружи адаптера - тоже плохая идея-наследник встроенных адаптеров. Они всё время с чем-нибудь да конфликтуют. Вот в `RecyclerView` такой проблемы в принципе не может возникнуть.

Comment: да, впринципе, адаптер больше дополнять не буду, осталось только слушатель на item для снятия/установки чекбокса и редактирования данных в БД. Ну и слушатель на долгое нажатие. Ну ничего ;) Подводные камни меня не пугают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от того, что именно возвращает БД можно подставлять `true`/`false` так:

```
(arrTblComplete.get(a).equals("0"))?false:true)?
```

или

```
(arrTblComplete.get(a)==0)?false:true)
```

Comment: заранее извиняюсь за этот комментарий, а зачем писать тернарный оператор а потом true/false? `arrTblComplete.get(a)==1` хуже чтоли? Просто не 1 раз вижу уже.

Comment: @pavel, чтоб потом грабли в нежданчике не поймать)

Comment: @pavel, ну... это... просто так на самом деле) Просто мне нравится как конструкция выглядит)))