# Как менять состояние Checkbox в айтемах ListView при нажатии на него

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

У меня есть `ListView` с собственным адаптером. В разметке есть чекбокс, чьё состояние нужно менять при нажатии на элемент списка, в котором он находится. Все бы хорошо, но и адаптер и модель находятся в отдельных классах, так как сам `ListView` инициализируется в отдельной `Activity`.

Можно ли осуществить это?

Comment: Этот вопрос уже более, чем [изжеван полностью](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=listview+checkbox)

Comment: @pavlofff, если я вот на этот ответ задублирую норм будет? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/17609

Comment: @pavlofff, ОК, а то у меня на андроид теперь золотой дубль-хаммер и я всё время опасаюсь не совсем верно повесить дубликат)

Comment: Ну и собственно, в [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/177345) есть все для полноценной реализации чекбоксов, если что то из этого ответа не понятно, укажите в своем вопросе и приложите код, который вы уже написали, чтобы решить (или создать :) ) эту проблему.

Comment: @pavlofff, все, я через view родителя в слушателе нахожу чекбокс и уже сделал все сам) осталась только одна проблема. чекбоксы при уходе с экрана и возвращения меняются

Comment: О "скачющих" чекбоксах тоже написано уже достаточно, в том числе и в ответе из комментариев выше. В вашей модели есть поле с текущим состоянием чекбокса, при генерации айтема в `getView()` адаптера, вам надо принудительно устанавливать состояние для чекбокса оттуда. При изменениях состояния записывать это в модель. Это связано с переиспользованием айтемов при создании списка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких вещей существует `interface`.

[Здесь пример, как его использовать](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)