# Как сохранить выбранные пункты CheckedTextView в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

По нажатию на кнопку открывается Диалоговое Окно в котором расположен `ListView`. А его пункты `CheckedTextView`. `ListView` мультивыборочный. Выбираю, все нормально работает. Но вот когда обратно открываю, то выбранных пунктов нету.

**Класс диалогового окна:**

```
public class DetailsSurchargeFragment extends DialogFragment {
private List<String> surchargeListNames = new ArrayList<>();
private List<SurchargeFare> surchargeFareList;
private List<SurchargeFare> selectedSurcharge = new ArrayList();

public RunnableUtils.RunnableParams onClickDismissRunnable;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getDialog().setTitle("Доплата за:");

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_surcharge_layout, container, false);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    listview.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.details_surcharge_item, R.id.text1, surchargeListNames));
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedSurcharge.add(surchargeFareList.get(position));
        }
    });

    Button mOk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    mOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();

            if (onClickDismissRunnable != null)
                onClickDismissRunnable.run(getSelectedSurcharge());
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public List<SurchargeFare> getSurchargeFareList() {
    return surchargeFareList;
}

public void setSurchargeFareList(List<SurchargeFare> surchargeFareList) {
    if (surchargeFareList != null && surchargeFareList.size() > 0) {
        this.surchargeFareList = surchargeFareList;
        for (int i = 0; i < surchargeFareList.size(); i++) {
            surchargeListNames.add(getSurchargeFareList().get(i).surcharge_title);
        }
    }
}

public List<SurchargeFare> getSelectedSurcharge() {
    return selectedSurcharge;
}
}
```

Вопрос: как сохранить выбранные пункты?

Comment: Магическим образом данные сами собой не сохранятся и не восстановятся. Запишите их, например, в SharedPreferences и оттуда и забирайте.

Answer (score 1):

у `ListView` есть метод `getCheckedItemPositions()`, который возвращает `SparseBooleanArray`, содержащий номера позиций, которые были изменены.

Перед выходом из активити (в методе `onPause()`) с `ListView`, эти данные нужно получить,где то отдельно сохранить, а потом при старте активити (в методе `onStart()`), по сохраненным ранее данным, восстановить отметки через метод `setItemChecked()`.

А проще решить этот вопрос, добавив в модель поле с текущим состоянием отметки и сохранять эти данные вместе с данными модели, хотя здесь уже потребуется писать собственный адаптер.

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/177345) немного писал об этом