# Не получается сделать ListView с чекбоксами и кнопкой, после нажатия которой в массив записываются все выбранные элементы

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день! 
Не получается сделать ListView с чекбоксами и кнопкой, после нажатия которой в массив записываются все выбранные элементы.
Как быть?

```
    String[] a = {"1","2","3"};

    selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    choiceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, a);
    choiceList.setAdapter(adapter);

    choiceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

как записать в другой массив отмеченные строки после нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: Покажи код, который не получается.

Comment: Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/177345) и примеры реализации, все они позволяют получить отметки чекбоксов в том или ином виде. Так же смотрите [реализацию варианта 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345) из ответа выше, метод которого `getChecked()` вернет отметки чекбоксов, вызывать этот метод вы можете и по нажатию кнопки (код для `RecyclerView`, но сам алгоритм подойдет и для `ListView` с минимальными изменениями)