# ListView с Checkbox'ами

Tags: android, listview

Есть ListView, необходимо при зажатии элемента включать режим выделения (у элементов появляются чекбоксы), чтобы можно было удалить выделенные

Comment: Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ. А вообще смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/177345)