# setOnItemClickListener корректно работает только для view, которые находятся на экране [on hold]

Tags: java, android, listview, kotlin, setonclicklistener

```
notesView.onItemClickListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
        override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            if(!selectMode) {
                var pos = notesView.indexOfChild(p1)
                NoteEditorHelper.openEditor(noteListAdapter.getItem(pos), pos)
            } else {
                var checkBox = p1?.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
                checkBox?.isChecked = true
            }
        }

    }
    notesView.setOnItemLongClickListener { arg0, arg1, pos, id ->
        if(!selectMode) {
            for (i in 0..notesView.childCount - 1) {
                var view = notesView.getChildAt(i)
                var checkBox = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
                checkBox.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                checkBox.isChecked = false
            }
            var checkBox = arg1.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
            checkBox.isChecked = true
            (activity as MainActivity).editNotesListModeOn()
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
```

Простенькое приложение для заметок. Хочу чтобы при нажатии на view открывалась соотвествующая ему заметка, а при зажатии все view отображали CheckBox'ы, но в реальности это всё срабатывает только для элементов находящихся на экране, а заметка открывается не та, что нужна. Это всё из-за особенностей работы ListView. Изначально был RecycleView, там та же история. LinearLayout мне не подходит. Как сделать так, чтобы listener'ы срабатывали на все view независимо от того видны они на экране или нет?

Comment: Отображением чекбоксов должен управлять адаптер. Посмотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/11515 и то же по `Recycler`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/11515. Если не получится реализовать , тогда дополняйте вопрос Вашей попыткой - поможем чем сможем.

Comment: Спасибо, чекбоксы починились, но появилась другая проблема, в отдельном сообщении выше опишу

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, один из методов помог и теперь чекбоксы отображаются корректно, но появилась другая проблема. Когда срабатывает click или long click открывается либо не та записка на которую нажали, меняется состояние не того чекбокса. В общем все действия в listener'ах применяются к заметкам где-то выше

```
`override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(noteList[position], activity)
        if(editMode) {
            holder.checkBox.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            holder.isChecked = false
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if(!editMode) {
                NoteEditorHelper.openEditor(noteList[position], position)
            } else {
                holder.isChecked = !holder.isChecked
            }
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            if(!editMode) {
                (activity as MainActivity).editNotesListModeOn()
                holder.itemView.callOnClick()
                notifyDataSetChanged()
                true
            } else {
              false
            }
        }
    }`
```