# Программное изменение(инициализация) элемента ListView (Android)

Tags: android, listview

Имеется ListView, содержащий массив имен, подгружаемый из XML файла. Единица ListView это элемент CheckedTextView.

При старте Activity происходит подключение к устройству, получение массива байт, эквивалентное массиву имен. Полученный массив содержит информацию о включенности того или иного имени, которое должно выражаться в наличии либо отсутствии галочки чекбокса.

**Вопрос** - как произвести инициализацию **всего** списка значениями включен/выключен(чекбокс установлен/снят)?

*Мои попытки инициализировать значения:*

```
for(int i = 0; i <= choiceModeList.getLastVisiblePosition() - 
                    choiceModeList.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {
     CheckedTextView chkd = 
     choiceModeList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
     chkd.setChecked(data[i]); }
```

В этом случае чекбоксы устанавливаются, но только для актуального вида (в случае прокрутки - значения пропадают).

*Тогда я попробовал создать свой ArrayAdapter и переопределить метод getView*

```
    //data - массив содержащий актуальное состояние чекбоксов для каждого элемента списка

    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    CheckedTextView checkbox;
    View tempView = convertView;

    if(tempView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        tempView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null, true);
        checkbox = tempView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        CharSequence[] chars = names;
        checkbox.setText(chars[position]);
        tempView.setTag(checkbox);

    } else {
        checkbox = (CheckedTextView) tempView.getTag();
    }

    if(data != null) {
        if (data[position] == 1) {
            checkbox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    return tempView;
}
```

Мне кажется, что я упускаю что-то очевидное и важное. Возможно, я как-то не так гуглю этот вопрос. Если у вас есть совет, или ссылка на материал/статью на русском/английском языке, то я с огромной благодарностью приму вашу помощь! Заранее вам спасибо!

**UPD**: Посмотрел запись конференции Google I/O от 2009-го года. Там этот момент разобрали достаточно подробно. Возможно, кому-нибудь пригодится:
https://youtu.be/N6YdwzAvwOA?t=119

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/177345

Comment: Посмотрел лекцию 2009-го года на конференции гугл. Там как раз об этом говорилось в начале. Всё стало намного понятнее.